# Could not find parameter map java.lang.Integer

Tags: mybatis

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.IncompleteElementException: Could not find parameter map java.lang.Integer
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.setStatementParameterMap(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:319)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.addMappedStatement(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:283)
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLStatementBuilder.parseStatementNode(XMLStatementBuilder.java:107)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.buildAllStatements(Configuration.java:698)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.hasStatement(Configuration.java:668)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.hasStatement(Configuration.java:663)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:180)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:43)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:58)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:51)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.selectListForType(Unknown Source)
at com.jhp.service.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.getListForType(DocumentServiceImpl.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.getListForType(Unknown Source)
at com.jhp.service.Impl.DocumentServiceImplTest.getListForType(DocumentServiceImplTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:172)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:335)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:330)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter Maps collection does not contain value for java.lang.Integer
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:797)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getParameterMap(Configuration.java:570)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.setStatementParameterMap(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:317)
    ... 56 more

**spring-context-mybatis.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"  
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<description>Mybatis Configuration</description>

<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath*:/conf/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.jhp"/>
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:/com/jhp/dao/mapping/*Mapper.xml"/>
    <property name="plugins">
        <array>
            <bean class="com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper">
                <property name="properties">
                    <value>
                        dialect=mysql
                        offsetAsPageNum=true
                        rowBoundsWithCount=true
                        pageSizeZero=true
                        reasonable=true
                    </value>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.jhp.dao" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**DocumentMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.jhp.dao.DocumentMapper" >


<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.jhp.model.Document" >
<id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
<result column="content" property="content" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
<result column="type" property="type" jdbcType="TINYINT" />
<result column="create_time" property="createTime" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
<result column="update_time" property="updateTime" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
<result column="shielded" property="shielded" jdbcType="TINYINT" />
</resultMap>
<resultMap type="com.jhp.dto.DocumentForListDTO" id="ListResultMap">
    <id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="content" property="content" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />   
</resultMap>

<select id="selectListForType" resultMap="ListResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.Integer">
    select id, content
    from document where shielded = 1 and type = #{type}
</select>
</mapper>
```

Comment: Providing some context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like if you are using the @Param annotation in your Mapper interface method. In that case you must remove the paramType attribute from the select tag.

Other possible explanation for the exception is that the type attribute is not a integer. If the real type is short, by example, you get the IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later but in my case, I had a mistake in another Mapper.xml.
I was putting resultMap instead of resultType and the error is so unclear.